# How would this STOP problem end up working?

Tags: algorithm

So hey,

I have a task from school, it's based on this code:

```
while(n != 1)
    {
        System.out.print(n + ", ");
        if(n%2 == 0)
        {
            n = n/2;
        }
        else
        {
            n = here;
        }
    }
```

Question is, what will happend if you change this line

```
n = here;
```

to 3n+2, 2n+1 and n+1
What I learned so far:
for 3n+2 if you run program and n will be 50 and another time 200, after certain point it will look exactly the same, although will not work for negatives numbers;
for 2n+1 won't work at all
for n+1 will work

Any good quality informations, how it will exactly work, I cant fully figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

The thing you are interested is [Collatz_conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) and variations.
It's supposed it's never goes to infinity, but we still have no proof.

Also I highly recommend to watch these small videos about it: [Collatz_conjecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5mFpVDpKX70), [variations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O2_h3z1YgEU).

Answer (score 0):

n%2 means the remainder. So with even number this equals 0 and uneven not.

When n comes in as not even, it will go to the else. 
So when you write:

```
n = n + 1. with following example: 

n=7, n != 1 so in the while, n%2 == 0 equals false, we go to else
n = n + 1, // now n =8
go back to top of while, n != 1 so in the while, n%2 == 0 equals true
n = n/2 //now n = 4
go back to top of while...
n = n/2 // now n = 2
go back to top of while...
n =n/2 // now n = 1
exit while
```

You can aslo debug your code to see what happen, other examples you can do thinking yourself :-)